# How to give apache web directory access to other FTP user where parent directory is restricted

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, ftp

I tried hard but not able to give access of web directory to other user for FTP.
Below are the directories which are under directory `/var/www/html`

```
1) nice_call
2) poor_call
3) great_call
```

/var/www/html is owned by apache user as well as all above mentioned directories is also owned by apache.

I just want to give read+write access to one more user named as `ftp_user` for directory `poor_call` not for other directories.
I am also ready to give 777 access to directory `poor_call` to resolve this issue.

Please note that I am having root access to execute any command to resolve this issue.
It will be great if someone can help on it.parent-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your user `ftp_user` so that they can FTP successfully into their home directory. Assuming you're using `vsftp` as your FTP server; you'll need the following as a minimum in your `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
```

Within the user's home directory create a directory called (eg) `poor_call`.

Then, bind mount `/var/www/poor_call` onto this newly created directory:

```
# mount --bind /var/www/poor_call /home/ftp_user/poor_call
```

After running the above command, `/var/www/poor_call` becomes accessible from `/home/ftp_user/poor_call`.

Once you've confirmed that it works, add the following to your `/etc/fstab` to make the bind mount permanent over reboots:

```
/var/www/poor_call /home/ftp_user/poor_call none bind 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine and exactly the same which i was looking for.